# Accessing portal for ArcGIS through web adaptor throws HTTP 404?

Tags: arcgis-server, installation, arcgis-portal, configuration

I'm in the process of configuring Web Adaptor with  Portal for ArcGIS . here's what happened . I Opened the Web Adaptor webpage then I was ordered to select a product to configure it with the Adaptor . I selected 'Portal for ArcGIS' , pressed next , then appeared a webpage with two lines :

**Not Found**

**HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.**

This is exactly what I have done . The authorization process was successful and Portal for ArcGIS Windows service is running fine .

Comment: I have a similar problem—trying to run `configurewebadaptor.sh` to link portal to the webadaptor, but no matter how I arrange the parameters, I get 'Unable to register web adaptor.Unable to register web adaptor. : {404 - Not Found}'. Did you ever find a solution?